# Does process have permission to view files on azure?

Tags: azure, fubumvc

I have recently deployed a fubu mvc application to windows azure. Everything works except when the pipeline tries to find the view to render. This all works correctly on my local machine.

So I am wondering: does the process on the Azure box have rights to read/scan files on disk?

Any suggestions to fix it are welcome though.

EDIT:
As part of the deployment there is a stage that azure goes through called "Preparing files for eployment". I checked on the log and my view was not in there

So I changed copy to output as true and it worked

Comment: Same thing happened to me on AppHarbor -- in this case I had to set the build action on my views to Content.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on where you are trying to read and how you have configured your roles.  By default, the code will run as a very low privilege user that only has R/W to the code directory (and any LocalResource(s) defined by the user).  However, you can run your code as SYSTEM, in which case you can R/W anywhere (you might still have to take ownership, but you are all powerful as SYSTEM).

If your views are defined as part of your package and uploaded, the code should have permission to view it.  I am curious as why you think this is a permission issue right now.  Do you see an error that indicates that, or are you guessing it?  If I had to guess, my first thought would be your views didn't get packaged correctly and are not on the VM.  You can confirm they are there either by RDP or by cracking open the package and snooping around.

Comment: The error from fubu indicates the view isn't even there. I asked for their advice on the fubu mailing list and the only suggestion I haven't ruled out is permissions. Thankyou for your reply

Comment: Also I'm not using a vm. I'm just using the free website option to get my site up and running